# Unusual SQL Server Exception 257 while attempting to rename a View

Tags: web-part, web-part-page

I've never seen this before. While attempting a routine UI operation -- changing the name of a view (but not changing its file name), I get a generic Sharepoint UI error. But the ULS log shows a more detailed - and unusual - error:

```
SqlError: 'Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed.
Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' 
  Number: 257 State: 3 Class: 16 Procedure: 'proc_UpdateView' LineNumber: 0
```

This error occurs while Sharepoint is attempting to execute the following *inline* SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @ListId uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @NewViewId uniqueidentifier; 
DECLARE @SiteId uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @@iRet int;
BEGIN TRAN;
  SELECT @ListId = @wssp0, @NewViewId = @wssp1, @SiteId = @wssp2;
  EXEC @@iRet=proc_UpdateView @SiteId, @ListId, @NewViewId, @wssp3, @wssp4, @wssp5, 
       @wssp6, @wssp7, @wssp8, @wssp9, @wssp10, @wssp11, @wssp12; 
  IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done; done: 
  IF @@iRet=0 BEGIN EXEC proc_UpdateDiskUsed @SiteId; COMMIT END ELSE ROLLBACK; 
  SET @wssp13=@@iRet;'     CommandType: Text CommandTimeout: 0     
    Parameter: '@wssp0' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input 
          Value: '3dcd6f35-c684-4fa3-8b5f-d5d9e3f32a37'     
    Parameter: '@wssp1' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input 
          Value: 'b0cb7911-583a-485a-baa1-3d7a1afb8ba0'     
    Parameter: '@wssp2' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input 
          Value: 'b40a0b88-dae5-41c2-8eb1-37630b1c611d' 
    Parameter: '@wssp3' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input 
          Value: '153'     
    Parameter: '@wssp4' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input 
          Value: 'False' 
    Parameter: '@wssp5' Type: NVarChar Size: 0 Direction: Input 
          Value: ''     
    Parameter: '@wssp6' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input 
          Value: 'DefaultSearch'     
    Parameter: '@wssp7' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input     
    Parameter: '@wssp8' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     
    Parameter: '@wssp9' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     
    Parameter: '@wssp10' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '1' 
    Parameter: '@wssp11' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     
    Parameter: '@wssp12' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     
    Parameter: '@wssp13' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Output Value:
```

Any idea what this might be? I've never seen this before.

Thanks in advance
Josh

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a definitive answer, but it seems to be faintly related to creating more than one view bearing the same Title. After I rewrote the relevant code to remove previous versions of the the view in question, this exception disappeared.

Chalk this one up to circumstantial evidence.